# How to fix TypeError: undefined is not an object error?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to add results of a file got using `XMLHttpRequest` to an array. The file is a json.

Here's a Code that creates the error:

```
var array = [];
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req("get", "test.json");
req.onreadystatechange = handle(req, array);
req.send();

function handle(req, array) {
    if ((req.target.readyState == 4) && (req.target.status == 200)) {
        var json = JSON.parse(req.target.responseText);
        array.push(json.test);
        alert(array);

    }
}
```

Without using `target` is has the value `4`

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: Rather use console.log(array) to test data results. And agreed @JulianKuchlbauer, where does the error occur at what line ?

Comment: And you have to write req.open("get", "test.json"); instead of just req(...

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer At line 8

Comment: What about not using target? What do you mean, it has the value 4

Comment: And it doesnt change? It always is 1 at first

Comment: No, when I check it using `alert()` it is 1 and then it returns the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong property of request.

Try with inline function for onreadystatechange callback

```
var array = [];
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req("get", "test.json");
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if ((req.readyState == 4) && (req.status == 200)) {
        var json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        array.push(json.test);
        alert(array);
    }
};
req.send();
```

or as per your way

```
var array = [];
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req("get", "test.json");
    req.onreadystatechange = handle();
    req.send();
function handle(){
         if ((req.readyState == 4) && (req.status == 200)) {
            var json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            array.push(json.test);
            alert(array);
        }
    };
```

Comment: The problem is, `array` and `req` are inside a function, and `handle` is a separate function.